# Is it possible to take stylus input in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, widget, drawing

I want to make a drawing app using Flutter. There is this widget called CustomPaint that allows you to easily have a Canvas and draw on it with you fingers.

Let's say that I want to use a tablet with a dedicated stylus will CustomPaint take into account the pressure sensitivity automatically.

If not, what should I do for my app to support the stylus.

I've been looking around for example apps and the only ones I found don't even mention the possibility of pressure sensitivity or even just plain usage with stylus.

Example apps

https://github.com/vemarav/signature

https://github.com/psuzn/draw-it

Comment: It seems like it, though I haven't looked to deeply into it. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/PointerData-class.html However, it's possible that it's not yet supported on Windows and Linus (Issues #65248 and #63209 under the Flutter repository)

Answer (score 1):

For basic input handling you would use the [`GestureDetector`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html) widget.

For low level input detection you can use the [`Listener`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Listener-class.html) widget that has `onPointerDown`, `onPointerMove`, `onPointerHover` and `onPointerUp` event listeners (and much more), which you can use to get the information of your stylus.

The information you can get from the listeners can be found under the according [`PointerEvent`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/gestures/PointerEvent-class.html) given by each event listener. One of the information you can get from `PointerEvent` is the [`pressure`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/gestures/PointerEvent/pressure.html).

You can find a basic introduction to input detection under [Taps, drags, and other gestures](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/advanced/gestures).